# Использование селекторов при множестве классов у элемента

Tags: css, css-selectors

Есть некий элемент, в котором куча разных классов. Используя селекторы мы можем подвязаться к нужному классу. Но, можно ли провернуть данную аферу, когда у элемента есть еще классы?

```css
div[class^="category-"][class$="-sets"]  {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-test-sets">test</div>
<div class="classname-test category-tset-sets test-classname">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте селектор `div[class*="category-"][class*="-sets"]`. Так будут найдены классы у которых есть подстрока `category-` и `-sets`

```css
div[class*="category-"][class*="-sets"] {
  color: red;
}

div[class*="-set"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-test-sets">test</div>
<div class="classname-test category-tset-sets test-classname">test</div>
<div class="class-sets">test</div>
```

Comment: что не спасает от случая `my-category-class-sets` для которого из кода в вопросе не применился бы стиль

Comment: @Grundy вы правы. В моем случае такой класс не генерируется, поэтому решение подойдет, хоть и имеет небольшой изъян при определенных условиях.